# What can this possibly mean? Inconsistent watch results in Visual Studio debugger

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging, cocos2d-x

[image]
[(big)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjtrd.png)

[image]
[(big)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyeVj.png)

Somewhere along the way into the function `animationWithFrames`, my vector loses its items.

This is actually a **CCMutableArray** which is a thin wrapper around std::vector.

```
template<class T = CCObject*>
class CCMutableArray : public CCObject
{
public:
    typedef std::vector<T>                              CCObjectArray;
    typedef typename CCObjectArray::iterator            CCMutableArrayIterator;
    typedef typename CCObjectArray::reverse_iterator    CCMutableArrayRevIterator;
public:
    // ... helper functions ...
private:
    std::vector<T> m_array;
};
```

What I don't get is, when I send the variable **frames** into the function, the debugger accepts that it has a variable m_array with 2 items in it.

But inside the function the variables seem to enter "ghost" form.

frames contains:

`m_array=[ 2 ](0x051d5078 ... )`

but expanding, m_array contains

`[0]()`.

**What would cause the debugger to be inconsistent like this?**

The code, by the way, does not see the items. They've vanished in transit. That's the problem.

Visual Studio 2010. Worked fine in 2008. I may downgrade in order to do some work.

Comment: Did you take the two screenshots without running the program in between? I.e. did you make a screenshot, move down the stack, and take a screenshot again?

Comment: @avakar: yep, same run (but the second screenshot is inconsistent with itself, so maybe the first isn't relevant, I dunno)

Comment: Can you show that function, and how you allocate the object you're passing around?

Comment: @Chris, it seems unlikely to me that the debugger would display the same pointer differently, when the memory is the same. It seems more likely that you took one screenshot, hit F10, and then took another one (in which case another thread or an overlapped I/O could have overwritten the memory). Alternatively, `frames` on the first screenshot is not `CCMutableArray<CCSpriteFrame *> *`, but something that converts to it. I'm not sure what you mean by the second screenshot being inconsistent.

Comment: I assure you, no stepping took place between the two screenshots

Comment: The second shot shows m_array with both 2 and 0 items

Comment: @ChrisBurt-Brown, oh, right, interesting :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a totally stupid issue where I was apparently linking in the 2008 build of cocos2d-x into the 2010 project.

The debugger didn't like that very much.

Rebuilding cocos2d-x inside 2010 make the problem go away and all was well.